# "Cowardly" as an adverb

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Is "cowardly" both an adjective and an adverb?

Question inspired by this awkward error message from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

> `Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew install'`

Surely there is another way to say so.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cowardly
What else would you choose? There's not much to choose from.

Comment: Here are some examples of it being used as an adverb: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cowardly%20hid%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Vote to reopen:  I'll note that no one has produced an example of the use of "cowardly" as an adverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, there are other ways to say it, such as *cravenly* (suggested by commenters) and *timidly*.

However, many dictionaries do indeed list *cowardly* as both an adjective and an adverb.

- [Google (Oxford Dictionaries Online, as pointed out by @EdwinAshworth)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20cowardly) (lists adverb form as archaic)
- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cowardly) (also lists adverb form as archaic)
- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cowardly)
- [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cowardly) (curiously, this one lists the adverb form first)

We do tend to use *cowardly* in its adjective form (e.g. "in a cowardly manner"), and that is probably why Google claims that the adverb form is archaic. However, as you demonstrated, the adverb form is still in use in some places today (or maybe the homebrew developers are ancient people--after all, many experienced guy programmers have beards).

It seems that tacking on *-ly* to a noun is often used to make it an adjective, and quite often, the adjective form is also usable as an adverb. Examples include (sentences self-composed):

- *daily*

  > The *daily* (adj.) schedule is posted on the board.
  >
  > I wash my clothes *daily* (adv.). (Aren't I a hygienic person?)
- *hourly*, *weekly*, *yearly*, etc.
- *leisurely*

  > Every night, the young man takes a *leisurely* (adj.) stroll down the street.
  >
  > She walked into the store and *leisurely* (adv.) examined the array of purses on display.
- [*womanly*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/likely)

Other words typically used as adjectives but also available as adverbs (@EdwinAshworth kindly pointed out that such adverbs are known as *flat adverbs*) include [*stately*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stately), [*lively*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lively), [*deadly*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deadly) (this one seems a bit different than the others: "*deadly* pale"), [*likely*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/likely) (probable or probably), and [*early*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stately) (this is not the typical *-ly* construction, as far as I'm aware). Note that, for some of the words above, Google does not list the adverb forms, but Dictionary.com does.

Exceptions exist too, such as *friendly* and *costly*.

The above lists are almost certainly incomplete, and I am sure that, as language changes, other adjectives will become adverbs, or nouns into adjectives into adverbs. At any rate, therefore, if you come buy an adjective that you'd like to use as an adverb, check it in the dictionary. If it's not there, but you *really* want to use it (and think it sounds right), get enough people to do the same thing, and Google might even change for you.

Comment: Thanks for the dual usage examples. _Leisurely_ as an adverb also sounds strange to me. I think my brain wants these to be "cowardably" and "leisurefully," or something...

Comment: Disclaimer: if you frequently use adjectives as adverbs, people will say that you talk *funny*.

Comment: Hello, Kye. A good answer (though 'Google Dictionary' should probably be 'Oxford Dictionaries Online'). But a lot of this has been covered here before (under say 'flat adverbs'), and OP should have shown at least some signs of research.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting and perhaps more correct adverbial form of cowardly is [*cowardlily*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cowardlily). This rule works for other -ly adjectives too:

> And yet the busy men found time to greet him friendlily : "H'are you!"

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/friendlily

Comment: I appreciate Contrum's contribution. It answers the question about whether there's another way to say cowardly as an adverb.

Answer (score -3):

**Cowardly** is not an adverb. A correct adverb would be *cravenly*.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cravenly

Comment: Dictionary.com lists it as an adverb (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cowardly?s=t). So does Google, although archaic (https://www.google.com/#q=define%20cowardly).

Comment: Even the dictionary you yourself cite for *cravenly* lists *cowardly* as an adverb (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cowardly).

Comment: Well, I'm going to disagree with you here and point you to the Cambridge Dictionary Online (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/coward) and the Oxford Dictionaries (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cowardly). Most mainstream dictionaries either do not list it as an adverb or warn that the usage is archaic.